# Would my downloaded Ubuntu, require an Internet Conncetion?

Tags: 12.04, iso, offline, setup, unetbootin

So I download a setup of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS of about 600 MB (don't remember the actual size) and burned it on a USB using unetbootin. 
So, Is that Ubuntu, the Offline Installer? 
As I cant  run online installer as I have a Broadband with a speed of 256 kbps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to install Ubuntu without an internet connection but you will not be able to download any of the extras or updates during the installation.

Once the installation is complete you can use the `Ubuntu Software Center`and the `Software Updater` utilities to download additional software and updates.

Answer (score 0):

12.04 Does not require an active internet connection to install , although it may be benefitial to have one during install as it will auto download some required packages by your machine.
Try running the installer again , I did not had any problems doing it offline on my laptop.

And you said you got a broadband with speed of 256 kbps.. so why not just plug in the ether cable? (wifi works too!)